# Выравнивание тега label

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать так, чтобы все строки `label` начинались на том же уровне, что и первая строка. В данный момент вторая строка начинается под радиобаттоном, нужно сдвинуть её вправо до уровня начала первой строки.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="layer in listLayers" class="ng-scope">
  <label class="ng-binding">
    <input type="radio" data-ng-model="layerSelect.id" value="269961" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="724">Test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test_ test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test_ (0)
  </label>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Могу предложить следующее решение... Оберните текст в какой нибудь элемент, например <span style="display: block;">.

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh, и чем же block поможет?

Comment: @Qwertiy тем, что задаст левую границу текста ...

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh, но тогда радиобаттон окажется выше блока, если не применить к нему float или абсолютное позиционирование.

Comment: @Qwertiy, для этого есть css ...

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh, для всего есть css, чего тогда на вопросы отвечать? ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, если моё предложение является не рабочим или не подходит - предлагаете свой и/или указываете, что не так в моём. Обсудим ...

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh, я свои варианты предложил. Кстати, за что минус варианту с text-indent?

Answer (score 1):

```css
label {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 16px;
  /* position is not required */
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -16px;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="r">Текст
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="r">Ещё текст
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="r">Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста...
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="r">Текст
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="r">Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста...
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="r">Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста...
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось просто, разнёс на два отдельных тега и сделал флоат лефт с фиксацией ширины у лейбла

Comment: В таком случае придётся заполнять id, чтобы работало for.

Answer (score -1):

```css
label {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

span {
  text-indent: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <span><input type="radio" name="r"></span>Текст
</label>
<label>
  <span><input type="radio" name="r"></span>Ещё текст
</label>
<label>
  <span><input type="radio" name="r"></span>Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста...
</label>
<label>
  <span><input type="radio" name="r"></span>Текст
</label>
<label>
  <span><input type="radio" name="r"></span>Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста...
</label>
<label>
  <span><input type="radio" name="r"></span>Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста... Много много много текста...
</label>
```

Comment: За что минусы-то?