# Отменить обтекание текстом input-а при условии 'мешающего' TextNode

Tags: html, css

Есть следующая конструкция (генерируемая без моего участия):

```
<span class="class1">
  <span class="class2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="property[]" value="val1">
    &nbsp;
    <span class="class3">Пояснение к чекбоксу</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Необходимо убрать обтекание чекбокса текстом, чтобы было как здесь: http://xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/content/overflow-and-orphans

Способ из ссылки выше работал бы, если бы не мешающий `&nbsp;`.
Есть ли способ справиться с этим? Желательно чистый CSS, без JavaScript.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468946/178988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1** задать отрицательный верхний отступ на величину размера высоты строки:

```css
input {
  display: block;  
  width: 20px; /*задайте свое необходимое значение */
  float: left;
}

.class3 {
    display: block; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -16px; /*высота строки */
}
```

```html
<span class="class1">
  <span class="class2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="property[]" value="val1">
    &nbsp;
    <span class="class3">Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

**Вариант 2** `position: absolute` к `input`:

```css
.class2 {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="class1">
  <span class="class2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="property[]" value="val1">
    &nbsp;
    <span class="class3">Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

**Вариант 3 flex**:

```css
.class2 {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="class1">
  <span class="class2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="property[]" value="val1">
    &nbsp;
    <span class="class3">Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу Пояснение к чекбоксу</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста (по ссылке), что именно я имею ввиду

Comment: Я видела ссылку, уточняйте что именно!!! Изображение и под ним текст или изображение слева, текст справа?!

Comment: Изменил вопрос, внес уточнения

Comment: Поправила ответ, выбирайте)))

Comment: Спасибо, самым подходящим для меня кажется 2, но там у первой строки получается отступ(пробел) из-за &nbsp;
Нет ли способа его.. игнорировать?)

Comment: лично я могу только опять же margin-left: -6px предложить ... думаю css-ом его не получиться удалить (

Answer (score 0):

```css
input{display: inline-block; float: left;  width: 20%;}
.class2{width: 400px;display: block;}
.class3{display: inline-block;width: 77%; float:left}
```

```html
<span class="class1">
  <span class="class2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="property[]" value="val1">
    &nbsp;
    <span class="class3">Пояснение к   к чекбоксуПоясне ние к чекб оксуПоясн ение к чек бок  уПоясне ние  к чекбок уПояснение к чек боксуП ояснение  к чекбоксуПояснение к чекбоксуПояснен ие к чекбоксуПоясн ение к чекбоксуclass2</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Типа такого?